# Using an MCP23008 IC with a 4X4 matrix keypad on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, matrix, keypad, expander

I want to be able to free up the native GPIO pins on my Raspberry Pi Zero. I know the MCP23008 gives me 8 extra pins, but I can't seem to find any resources on using the additional pins with a 4X4 matrix keypad.

Comment: Please ask a question. Also, interfacing anything to an IO expander has exactly same concept than interfacing directly to an MCU IO. The actual implementations of setting pin directions, writing output states, and reading input states are just different.

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98440/multiple-gpio-buttons-vs-matrix-keypad. Cheers.

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys. I will make sure to post a question properly in the future.